# Azure DevOps CI Pipeline - How to dynamically checkout branches?

Tags: azure-devops, automation, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

**The setup:**
I have a database repo and a unit-test repo that tests the database repo, both of these share a project in Azure DevOps. I have a CI pipeline that resides in the database project that is triggered on pushes to the remote-tracking branch. The trigger will run the CI when any branch in that directory is pushed to.

**The problem:**
I need to check out the unit-test project as well so that I can call it. We won't know what names topic branches will have until we create the tasks etc, how can this be captured dynamically?

**So an engineer can work on more than 1 branch with CI support** without having to worry about tidy up if urgency is raised.

I have read this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details.

I tried:

```
trigger:
- dev/a/*

steps:

- checkout: git://proj/repo-a@dev/a/*
- checkout: git://proj/repo-b@dev/a/*
```

Just to see if it was possible to get projects side-by-side.

**It raises error:**

> The pipeline is not valid. Could not get the latest source version for
> repository repo-a hosted on Azure Repos using ref
> refs/heads/dev/a/*. Could not get the latest source version for
> repository repo-b hosted on Azure Repos using ref
> refs/heads/dev/a/*.

I also tried the above without the wildcard, no joy. Another point is that I would not want to checkout all branches, just the branch with the push.

Surely this is possible ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To dynamically checkout branches, you can use the predefined variable: `Build.SourceBranchName`.

For example:

```
- checkout: git://proj/repo-a@$(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

Since you have referenced two repos, you also need to add a If expression to determine which repo trigger the build and use the target repo branch name.

You can use the variable: `Build.Repository.Name`

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'repo-a') }}:
  - checkout: git://proj/repo-a@$(Build.SourceBranchName)
- ${{ if eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'repo-b') }}:
  - checkout: git://proj/repo-b@$(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

Or you can use condition.

For example:

```
- checkout: git://proj/repo-a@$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  condition: eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'repo-a')
- checkout: git://proj/repo-b@$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  condition: eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'repo-b')
```

Here is the docs about [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) and [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: I checked out both branches using this approach, great stuff.